# simple redirect() function not working in symfony 1.4

Tags: redirect, controller, symfony-1.4

I am assuming I'm doing something blatantly wrong here, but I can't figure out what. My code is very simple:

```
public function executeForward(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  //redirect traffic that has landed here to either advertiser's or our own lander
  if ( rand(1, 100) > 50 )
  {
    $this->redirect( 'http://www.google.com', 404 );
  }
  else
  {
    $this->redirect( 'http://www.bing.com', 404 );
  }
}
```

I know the template is loading this action as I can write sloppy code in this action and it will 500 in my browser. On top of that, here is the basic route:

```
forward_page:
  url:   /forward
  param: { module: static, action: forward }
```

Do any of your symfony masters have a painfully obvious answer as to why this doesn't work? I'd greatly appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

404 is an error code : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404
Try a 302 code, it's indicate a redirection. BY the way, it's the default value of this option:
http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/action/sfAction.class.php

Comment: I've tried entering 302, and tried allowing it to default to 302 as well. I'm aware of the default behaviour and what the error codes mean. Thanks for the effort though!

Comment: Ok, excuse me to have misunderstood your problem. By the way, I have tested your code, and it works !

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. I think the problem is with $this->redirect. As far as I could understand, $this->redirect expects the first parameter to be a symfony route. It does not accept external URLs. Not sure I am correct.